# Does Google Cloud DataProc provide a web page with default JVM and YARN settings?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

As a former user of `Apache Hadoop` on `AWS Elastic-Map-Reduce` (EMR) service, I'm used to fetching information from a static page here[1] about the default deployment settings for various sized VMs in an `EMR` cluster. The settings include JVM max memory size, `YARN` scheduler min/max memory allocations, Map and Reduce max memory, etc.

Is there is a similar web page with the corresponding information for the `Google Cloud` (GCP) `DataProc` service? I checked and couldn't find one...

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html#emr-hadoop-task-jvm

Answer (score 3):

This kind of information is available through DataProc CLI tool. If you need to find out the defaults, launch a provisioning operation and then use the operation's ID to execute

```
    gcloud dataproc operations describe ID
```

Details of the command are available here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/operations/describe

You'll get back the types of settings you described and more. For example:

```
    capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.ordering-policy: fair
    core:fs.gs.block.size: '134217728'
    core:fs.gs.metadata.cache.enable: 'false'
    distcp:mapreduce.map.java.opts: -Xmx768m
    distcp:mapreduce.map.memory.mb: '1024'
    distcp:mapreduce.reduce.java.opts: -Xmx768m
    distcp:mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb: '1024'
    hdfs:dfs.datanode.address: 0.0.0.0:9866
    hdfs:dfs.datanode.http.address: 0.0.0.0:9864
    hdfs:dfs.datanode.https.address: 0.0.0.0:9865
    hdfs:dfs.datanode.ipc.address: 0.0.0.0:9867
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.handler.count: '20'
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.http-address: 0.0.0.0:9870
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.https-address: 0.0.0.0:9871
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.lifeline.rpc-address: three-node-cluster-j6q2al2mkkqck-m:8050
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address: 0.0.0.0:9868
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.secondary.https-address: 0.0.0.0:9869
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.service.handler.count: '10'
    hdfs:dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address: three-node-cluster-j6q2al2mkkqck-m:8051
    mapred-env:HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_HEAPSIZE: '3840'
    mapred:mapreduce.job.maps: '21'
    mapred:mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps: '0.95'
    mapred:mapreduce.job.reduces: '7'
    mapred:mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores: '1'
    mapred:mapreduce.map.java.opts: -Xmx2457m
    mapred:mapreduce.map.memory.mb: '3072'
    mapred:mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores: '1'
    mapred:mapreduce.reduce.java.opts: -Xmx2457m
    mapred:mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb: '3072'
    mapred:mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: '256'
    mapred:yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts: -Xmx2457m
    mapred:yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores: '1'
    mapred:yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb: '3072'
    presto-jvm:MaxHeapSize: 12288m
    presto:query.max-memory-per-node: 7372MB
    presto:query.max-total-memory-per-node: 7372MB
    spark-env:SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY: 3840m
    spark:spark.driver.maxResultSize: 1920m
    spark:spark.driver.memory: 3840m
    spark:spark.executor.cores: '2'
    spark:spark.executor.instances: '2'
    spark:spark.executor.memory: 5586m
    spark:spark.executorEnv.OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS: '1'
    spark:spark.scheduler.mode: FAIR
    spark:spark.sql.cbo.enabled: 'true'
    spark:spark.yarn.am.memory: 640m
    yarn-env:YARN_TIMELINESERVER_HEAPSIZE: '3840'
    yarn:yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb: '12288'
    yarn:yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb: '12288'
    yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb: '1024'
```